# java.lang.NullPointerException with WebView

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am having a webview , when i am typing on a new URL my webview downloads it .
in addition to that , the webview is hiding my buttons and editexts that are on the screen . how can i make those buttons to not be hidden while the webview is reloading?
thanks .

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
 WebView ourBrow=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
```

to

```
 ourBrow=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
```

Comment: Your answer is not valid. Please give some justification.

Comment: @MD See his code he declare WebView ourBrow at class level and again he declare it in onCreate().  When onClick method is called it refer to the class level variable and that variable not initialized thats why he get NullPointerException.